# Keyboard Shortcut for Frequent from Pinned program

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, pinning

I got to know the [pinned programs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/pin-a-program-to-the-taskbar) in taskbar and using it for Excel, Outlook, Chrome. I have put frequent files/urls to those pinned programs which I will get by right clicking the pinned program from taskbar.

There is a keyboard shortcut **Win + T** to go through the pinned programs of taskbar and **Menu/Shift+F10** to simulate right click action, but it is not showing the frequent list from the pinned program. I would like to know how can I see that frequent list of a pinned program with a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft article [Keyboard shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts) lists this keyboard shortcut,
which might be the one you are looking for :

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>
>
> Open the Jump List for the program pinned to the taskbar in the
>   position indicated by the number.